# make two api call from angular component and one of them always never happend

Tags: angular, typescript, api

I use Angular to write two service and one component. two service is similar and is used for different api call.
I tried to make api call from this component using two service, however, always only the first call is successfully, the second one always never happened

The reason I said the second call never made is: I own the server code. I am watching the server all the time, only the first API has ever been called. and two API is from same server. It is not network problem.

two service is similar, kind as following

```
    export class Service1{

      constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

      public get(): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.get<any>(url).pipe(
          map((res: any) => {
             return res.data;
          }),);}
```

component is as following

```
    export class Component implements OnInit {
      data1= this.service1.get();
      data2= this.service2.get();

      constructor(
        private service1: Service1, private service2:Service2) { }

      ngOnInit() {
        console.log(data1,data2);
      }
```

I expect two api in two service will call two different endpoint, but only the first call is made. the second one always never happened. The first call one works as expect.

Comment: This is an Angular question, not AngularJs.

Comment: Why are you saying the second call is never made? You cant see it in the network tab or you are just not seeing the data from the console.log?

Comment: @ukn The reason I said the second call never made is: I own the server. I am watching the server all the time, only the first API has ever been called. and two API is from same server. so it is not network problem. it is just the second call never happened

Comment: Check the browser network tab. If it's not there try commenting the working call and keeping the other

Comment: It's not just second service never made the request, it's both. Why? Because you never subscribed to either of em. Unless you subscribed on one of your `Service` via on your service class.

Comment: @penleychan I am very very sure the first call is made successfully.

Comment: Not sure how that is possible based on your code. Observable instance begins publishing values only when someone subscribes to it. You subscribe by calling the subscribe() method of the instance, passing an observer object to receive the notifications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to subscribe to each of the HTTP requests otherwise they won't be made. Then in the subscribe you can assign the response to data1 and data2 respectively in the component.

See the Angular docs for the [HttpClient](https://angular.io/guide/http):

> An HttpClient method does not begin its HTTP request until you call subscribe() on the observable returned by that method. This is true for all HttpClient methods.

So Service1 and Service2 would be as follows:

```
export class Service1 {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  public get(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get<any>('your-url').pipe(
      map((res: any) => {
        return res.data;
      })
    );
  }
}
```

And your component would look like this:

```
export class Component implements OnInit {
  data1;
  data2;

  constructor(private service1: Service1, private service2: Service2) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.service1.get().subscribe(res => (this.data1 = res));
    this.service2.get().subscribe(res => (this.data2 = res));
  }
}
```